# Record Date within Report Query

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am dissecting a report that was written by a previous employee. Can someone help me understand these lines?

Essentially I have been asked to find out if the report is pulling 2017 or 2018 data and these two lines are the only parameters within them.

```
AND RecordDate >= CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) >=10 THEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 10,1) ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,10,1) END

AND RecordDate < CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) >=10 THEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())+1, 10,1) ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),10,1) END
```

Answer (score 0):

This pair of conditions dynamically filter the dataset for the a dynamic period that ranges from the first  of October to end of September, like a fiscal year.

```
CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) >=10
    THEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 10,1)    
    ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,10,1) 
END
```

The first `case` expression computes the lower bound of the period: it gives you October 1st of last year if current date is before October 1st, else October 1st this year (i.e. a new fiscal year started).

The other expression uses similar logic to compute the upper bound.